# How did Thor get out of London Underground?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor: The Dark World*, Thor got teleported to Charing Cross station in London Underground thanks to gravitational anomaly. Fortunately, a train was waiting for him which could take him to Greenwich within 3 stops.

But, how did he get out of Greenwich station without ticket or card? I have never used London Underground, but I believe it'll fine you if you don't have ticket or card. And, if you fail to pay the fine (the case of Thor without money), you'll be arrested. Did Thor beat the security guys to get out of there?

Comment: He's instantly recognisable. I'm assuming he just walked through the barrier without being challenged

Comment: For me the bigger question is how he managed to get from Charing Cross to  Greenwich on the Circle Line **in three stops**. I know it's a fantasy film, but come on. That's just crazy-talk.

Comment: The writers probably weren't familiar with the layout and just made up something.

Comment: @Asking - Indeed. And it's not like you can do a quick search on the internet for a tube map or that the British cast/crew would know that it's wrong.

Comment: @Valorum Now, I see. That blonde girl lied to have company with Thor for some time.

Comment: @user931 - They can just go round and round in circles all afternoon

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thor is trying to get to Greenwich because it is **currently under attack by Dark Elves**.  Anyone there who has the authority to try and stop a world-famous Asgardian in full battle armor for fare jumping has more important things to worry about.

It is conceivable that he might have been stopped if he had tried to enter the Underground, but fortunately for him his portal opened up past any fare checkpoints.